# Obtaining the text from a web heading

Tags: html, excel, vba

I keep getting Run-time error '91' while trying to obtaining the text from a web heading.

The header html is:

```
<h1 class="af-heading heading-style-inline" id="metricValue">2202</h1>
```

And the VBA Code is:

```
Sub test()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ht As HTMLDocument

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate ("XXXXXX")

Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set ht = ie.document
MsgBox ht.getElementById("metricValue").innerText

End Sub
```

I'm getting the error in the MsgBox line: 'Onbect variable or With block variable no set'

Comment: The missing object is getElementById("metricValue"). Don't ask me why the element can't be extracted. I just tell you that that is the likely cause of the error. However, there is another possibility that ht doesn't get set and is proclaimed "missing" on the next line. Interject tests to ascertain which case you are dealing with.

Comment: Put a wait before that line and see if error goes away

Comment: Personally I've found `READYSTATE.....` to be useless. It can be "ready" when the page isn't fully loaded...

Comment: readystate <> 4 should be combined with while .busy, and yes, with modern webpages it is often better to look for a different change in the page to assess when a particular element is present/changed in value.